# Simultaneous equations with matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am about to start a PhD in zoology. At the moment, I am looking at matrices, as I have never looked at them before, and will need some further maths during my PhD.

I have found a question in the textbook where I need to solve simultaneous equations using matrix algebra.

$$ \begin{aligned} 2x + 3y &= 3 \\ 6x + 5y &= 0 \end{aligned} $$

Usually, I am quite good at figuring these out, for example, in an integral or differential situation. However, I don't even know where to get started when "using matrix algebra" is concerned. If anybody could offer me the tiniest piece of guidance I'd be grateful.

Comment: What field is it that you wanted to start your Ph.D. in? Start with "use common sense."

Comment: Actually it is a branch of chemical zoology. I've never done matrices before.

I thought this website would be totally against users like you existing here.

Comment: I'm trying to educate myself.

Comment: I suggest you start with an introductory linear algebra textbook.  MIT has an on-line course http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-06-linear-algebra-spring-2010/ that seems quite good.

Comment: I'm sorry if my honesty offended you. What do you think that the role of math.stackexchange might be?

Comment: Guidance in education. 
Helping each other to become better.
If you came over to my department I wouldn't slate you, I'd help you.
It's never shameful in this life to know when you're out of your depth and to want to do something about it.

Comment: I agree that guidance in education is important. But you have to meet us somewhere down the line - a statement of "I don't even know where to get started" isn't helpful, to say the least. I'd expect that you tried something, and it didn't work, and you showed us what you tried.

Comment: I've derived an answer. It's below.

Answer (score 1):

The question may be formulated as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\6&5\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
You solve it by finding the inverse of the leftmost matrix and multiplying by that inverse from the left to obtain
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix} =\begin{bmatrix}2&3\\6&5\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}3\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
which means that $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}x\\y\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ may be found by calculating the product on the right-hand side.

Comment: I've calculated the inverse of the left matrix and I have the values

A = -5/8
B = 3/8
C = 3/4
D = -1/4

Comment: I feel really stupid saying this but I'm incredibly lost. I usually can figure things out but I'm going to go and get a textbook from the library tomorrow.

So all I need to do is multiply the new inverse 2x2 matrix by the 2x1 matrix and I'm on the correct path?

Comment: Okay I've gone away and studied some more and have derived an answer of 

x = -15/8
y = 9/4

Assuming I am correct thanks for your assistance Arthur, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution for this question is as follows for any future readers of this post:

x = -15/8

y = 9/4

Answer (score 0):

[Cramer's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule) helps.

For an $n \ \times \ n$ matrix.

$\sum_{b=1}^n\lambda^a_bx^b=y^a \iff \lambda^a_bx^b=y^a\implies x^b=[\lambda ^a_b]^{-1}y^a $

With the notation in the middle, [Einstein summation notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation), matching upper and lower indices are summed over, $a$ is row, $b$ is column of the matrix. A single raised index implies implies the $a_{th}$ coordinate of the matrix.

For matrix multiplication you sum the column of one over the rows of the other, i.e. $A^a_bB^b_c=M^a_c$, where $M$ is the matrix product.

$det(\lambda^a_b)=\sum  \lambda_{i1}\lambda_{j2}\lambda_{k3}...(-1)^\pi$
where the sum is over $n!$ permuations of $i,j,k,...$ for $n$ of those and $\pi$ is the parity of the permutation, even or odd, each of $i,j,k,...$ are distinct.

Suppose $i=p$. Then $det(\lambda^a_b)=\sum_{p=1}^n\lambda_{p1}[\sum 
\lambda_{j2}\lambda_{k3}...(-1)^\pi]$ Where the term in brackets is called the cofactor which can be used to form a matrix in its own right, $C^a_b$.

It can be proven $[\lambda^ a_b]^{-1}=[C^a_b]^T/det([\lambda^a_b])$. In other words, the inverse is equal to the transpose of the cofactor matrix divided by the determinant, where the transpose of a matrix is the matrix flipped along the main diagonal, i.e. rows are switched with columns.

$C_a^by^a/det([\lambda^a_b])=x^b$ where the various numerators are the determinants of Cramer's Rule.

Comment: Please don't waste your time and ours by posting complicated answers to old questions that already have perfectly adequate answers, including one by the OP.

Comment: I think everything here could and should be taught in an introductory linear algebra course. Pretty sure in my course this definition of the determinant was used. Much later I'm not sure how to do genral determinant proofs without it.